# SQL : Syntax Error (near "from": syntax error)

Tags: sql

```
select 
    rf.policy_type_code, rf.policy_type_name,
    up.policy_type_id, up.user_id, up.policy_no
from 
    ref_policy_types rf 
join
    policy_sub_types ps 
join 
    user_policies up on rf.policy_type_code = ps.policy_type_code 
                     and up.policy_type_id = ps.policy_type_id
where 
    extract(month from adddate(up.date_registered, interval ps.maturityperiod month)) = '7'
    and extract(year from adddate(up.date_registered, interval ps.maturityperiod month)) = '2013';
```

Comment: You need one ON for each JOIN.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Also specify which `from` is causing the problem, if you have that information.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.Please also check if the SQL function name and their paramaters are in correct order.

```
SELECT rf.policy_type_code,
       rf.policy_type_name,
       up.policy_type_id,
       up.user_i d,
       up.policy_no
FROM ref_policy_types rf
    JOIN policy_sub_types ps
        ON rf.policy_type_code = ps.policy_type_code
    JOIN user_policies up
        ON up.policy_type_id = ps.policy_type_id;
where extract(month from adddate(up.date_registered,interval ps.maturityperiod month))='7' 
and extract(year from adddate(up.date_registered,interval ps.maturityperiod month))='2013';
```

Answer (score 0):

The missing `on` clause is definitely a syntax error (at least in most databases; in MySQL the `on` is optional).  However, I am not sure it would generate the error in your question.

The comparison of an integer (from `extract())` to a string is awkward -- you should not mix types.  In addition, I would recommend just using dates for this.  I prefer direct date arithmetic:

```
select rf.policy_type_code, rf.policy_type_name,
       up.policy_type_id, up.user_id, up.policy_no
from ref_policy_types rf join
     policy_sub_types ps
     on rf.policy_type_code = ps.policy_type_code join
     user_policies up
     on up.policy_type_id = ps.policy_type_id
where adddate(up.date_registered, interval ps.maturityperiod month) >= '2013-07-01' and
      adddate(up.date_registered, interval ps.maturityperiod month) < '2013-08-01';
```